# why does my grayscaled image have a larger size than the color image

Tags: python, image, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing

image in question : http://cdn1.ouchpress.com/media/celebrities/539/kate-upton-401846.jpg

I'm trying to convert the image to grayscale using the below command

```
img = cv2.imread('kate.jpg',cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

cv2.imwrite('kategray.jpg',img)
```

however the grayscaled image is of size 700kB whereas the color image is only 500kB.

What am i missing ? Since the color information is removed and the alpha channel is removed.

Shouldn't the image have a smaller size ?

Comment: Alpha channel on a .jpg ? Am I missing something ? About the weight increase : color informations is probably not the only thing removed, so might be a lot of optimizations in the source image (run-lenght encoding, color palette, ...). Only my guess, though.

Comment: I guess my information on channels is wrong. So Only png has the alpha channel ?  Either way. Still confused why removing color increases size of image on disk

Comment: png has, jpeg hasn't. I think gif also has one, but it only has 256 colors, so I never use it ...

Comment: JPEG is an image format using (lossy) compression. Different parameters will result in different image sizes.

Comment: To elaborate, the [default quality setting](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=imwrite) for `imwrite` is 95. The source image appears to have been saved with quality around 85 (to get that size). You need to compare images generated using the same settings, for the comparison to be meaningful. Also keep in mind that JPEG doesn't use RGB internally.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in their [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgcodecs/doc/reading_and_writing_images.html), if you don't specify the `params`, they'll get set to a default value.

This is what they say there:

> For JPEG, it can be a quality ( CV_IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY ) from 0 to 100 (the higher is the better). Default value is 95.

So, here you have it. [JPEG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG) is a **compressed format**, so file size depends on the *compression rate*.

What I assume is that your original image has a **lower compression rate than the defaulted `95` in opencv**.

If you want to lower your file size, try to specify a lower compression rate as the third argument `params` the following way:

(I assume a compression rate of 85%)

```
cv2.imwrite('kategray.jpg', img, 85)
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue stems from how you read in the image. You're using `cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE` which will convert the image to 16bit grayscale. If your original image only has an 8bit depth, it will grow in size due to the 1-byte difference in space required. To maintain the original bit depth of the image, you should read it in like this:

`cv2.imread('kate.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE | cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYDEPTH);`

The `CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYDEPTH` flag will make sure your original pixel depth is maintained.